# How to fetch rides that last for just 5 minutes

Tags: mysql, database

I need to analyze to fetch rides that are on the table I'm investigating (called rides) using SQL language, I need rides that lasted less than 5 minutes (I have the column ride_started_at and ended_at with different timestamps, when the ride started and when it ended) How would I do that? I couldn't find something similar anywhere.

Thanks!

I tried to use

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), ended_at)  >= 5
```

and also tried:

```
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,ride_created_at,NOW()) > 5
```

But I'm not advanced on SQL so I probably used the wrong code while I was trying to experiment.

Comment: what is the type of `ride_started_at`?

Comment: ride_started_at uses timestamps as 2015-10-17 03:01:20, the same for ended_at

Comment: It might be json,

Answer (score 0):

Use <5

```
      Where TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,ride_started_at,ended_at)<=5
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I try to use it and it tells me that minute is not a column. Why could it be?